I want to implement advanced search-bar in my angular app their is nothing in angular material what to do?
I want to implement advanced search-bar in my angular app for applying filters. for searching of logs, under kibana inside logs the search-bar is present i want to implement same as that.
I did not find any thing like that in angular material please help me with code or with repository.
i want to build advanced search-bar in my angular project. and i want this feature to implement in angular material.

build your own advanced searching bar with the components you get from angular materials.

Why do you must use material library? You said "please help me with code or repository". For the latter: you can try devex components as well.

Are you asking about to how create the UI controls for the search, or how to do the search once you have the criteria?
